# How do you do the jump start in Beach Buggy Racing?

Tags: beach-buggy-racing

I've noticed that in Beach Buggy Racing the cars sometimes do a jump start, what is the trick to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You do this by pressing the power-up button roughly half a second after the three dots appear. See here (also the source):

Comment: Is the powerup button the one that triggers you special power later in the race? (its a little different on the apple tv)